# How to make fade animation in nyroModal make faster?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, nyromodal

Anybody knows how to speed up the fade in and fade out animation of nyroModal?

Right now I am intializing it like this :

```
<a href="demoSent.php" class="nyroModal" rev="modal">Ajax without closing</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('.nyroModal').nyroModal();
});
</script>
```

And that's all.

However, the animation after clicking my links for the modal box is a little bit slow for my liking.

How can I make it faster? The documentation for nyroModal is quite difficult to understand, at least for me, so, any advice will be helpful.

**UPDATE:**
In the jquery file `jquery.nyroModal.custom.js` is this code for the animation, at least I guess:

```
/*
 * nyroModal v2.0.0
 *
 * Fade animations
 *
 * Depends:
 *
 */
jQuery(function($, undefined) {
    $.nmAnims({
        fade: {
            showBg: function(nm, clb) {
                nm.elts.bg.fadeTo(250, 0.7, clb);
            },
            hideBg: function(nm, clb) {
                nm.elts.bg.z(clb);
            },
            showLoad: function(nm, clb) {
                nm.elts.load.fadeIn(clb);
            },
            hideLoad: function(nm, clb) {
                nm.elts.load.fadeOut(clb);
            },
            showCont: function(nm, clb) {
                nm.elts.cont.fadeIn(clb);
            },
            hideCont: function(nm, clb) {
                nm.elts.cont.css('overflow', 'hidden').fadeOut(clb);
            },
            showTrans: function(nm, clb) {
                nm.elts.load
                    .css({
                        position: nm.elts.cont.css('position'),
                        top: nm.elts.cont.css('top'),
                        left: nm.elts.cont.css('left'),
                        width: nm.elts.cont.css('width'),
                        height: nm.elts.cont.css('height'),
                        marginTop: nm.elts.cont.css('marginTop'),
                        marginLeft: nm.elts.cont.css('marginLeft')
                    })
                    .fadeIn(function() {
                        nm.elts.cont.hide();
                        clb();
                    });
            },
            hideTrans: function(nm, clb) {
                nm.elts.cont.css('visibility', 'hidden').show();
                nm.elts.load
                    .css('position', nm.elts.cont.css('position'))
                    .animate({
                        top: nm.elts.cont.css('top'),
                        left: nm.elts.cont.css('left'),
                        width: nm.elts.cont.css('width'),
                        height: nm.elts.cont.css('height'),
                        marginTop: nm.elts.cont.css('marginTop'),
                        marginLeft: nm.elts.cont.css('marginLeft')
                    }, function() {
                        nm.elts.cont.css('visibility', '');
                        nm.elts.load.fadeOut(clb);
                    });
            },
            resize: function(nm, clb) {
                nm.elts.cont.animate({
                    width: nm.sizes.w,
                    height: nm.sizes.h,
                    top: (nm.getInternal().fullSize.viewH - nm.sizes.h - nm.sizes.hMargin)/2,
                    left: (nm.getInternal().fullSize.viewW - nm.sizes.w - nm.sizes.wMargin)/2
                }, clb);
            }
        }
    });
    // Define fade aniamtions as default
    $.nmObj({anim: {def: 'fade'}});
});
```

But I am clueless how to alter this code so the animation is faster.

Any idea?

Comment: Please post a working example snippet for us to fiddle with.

Comment: I don't think it's so important, because html is not important in this case, but I have updated the question with some code.

Comment: Here is some older issue with similar problem like mine. The author say something about rewriting the plugin, but it's vague: https://github.com/nyroDev/nyroModal/issues/171 Do you understand what is he saying?

Comment: All I can do is `$.nmObj({anim: {def: 'fade'}});` but no speed settings etc. The fade is the only option btw. ;D

Comment: I have added the part of the plugin js file where the animation is written if it helps. Any idea what should I change there so the animation is faster?

Answer (score 0):

```
        showBg: function(nm, clb) {
            nm.elts.bg.fadeTo(200, 0.7, clb);
        },
        hideBg: function(nm, clb) {
            nm.elts.bg.fadeOut(200, clb);
        },
        showLoad: function(nm, clb) {
            nm.elts.load.fadeIn(200, clb);
        },
        hideLoad: function(nm, clb) {
            nm.elts.load.fadeOut(200, clb);
        },
        showCont: function(nm, clb) {
            nm.elts.cont.fadeIn(200, clb);
        },
        hideCont: function(nm, clb) {
            nm.elts.cont.css('overflow', 'hidden').fadeOut(200, clb);
        },
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help the questioner understand your answer better, you should add at least some explanations. Thank you.